# HMS core Map kit, map loads but no rendering

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I am testing the map kit from Huawei.

The app has been created in App Gallery Connect and I did all the steps.
Other HMS services working just right.
All my dependencies are right.

So, I use a view to represent the map.

The `onMapReady` is called, view loads, I can interact with the map, add pins, find my location, etc.
But I cant see the map, only blank tiles.

I dont get an error, `onMapReady` is called just fine.

Also i have tried the demo from Huawei's Github, the result is the same.
I have tried with fragment too, same result.

My `mapView`

```
  <com.huawei.hms.maps.MapView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    map:cameraTargetLat="48.893478"
    map:cameraTargetLng="2.334595"
    map:cameraZoom="8.5"/>
```

My `onCreate`

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_huawei_map_test);
    Log.d(TAG, "yo: ");
    if (!hasPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS)) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, RUNTIME_PERMISSIONS, 100);
    }
    mMapView = findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    Bundle mapViewBundle = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mapViewBundle = savedInstanceState.getBundle(MAPVIEW_BUNDLE_KEY);
    }
    MapsInitializer.setApiKey("");//my key
    mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
    mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
```

My `onMapReady`

```
 @Override
public void onMapReady(HuaweiMap map) {
    //get map instance in a callback method
    Log.d(TAG, "onMapReady: ");
    hMap = map;
    //hMap.setMapType(HuaweiMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
    hMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    hMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595), 10));
    Marker mMarker = hMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(48.893478, 2.334595)));
    mMarker.showInfoWindow();

}
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your very detailed question. At first it looked like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606479/huawei-map-is-not-rendering-and-displays-white-screen-returns-http-status-code-5) already discussed problem but you did not receive any errors.

A common undetected error is that you did not sign your app properly. Try to clone the official [codelab repository](https://github.com/huaweicodelabs/MapKit) and compile the code from there. You need to sign your app with your own key and provide the corresponding SHA fingerprint on the AGC console.

For reference check out [this](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSPreparation/index.html#0) codelab on how to create a signing certificate.

I've tried the repository I linked above, changed the package name, swaped the App ID, filled in the API Key and added the agconnect json file.

On the AGC console I put in the right SHA fingerprint but signed my app with the wrong key. After rebuilding I was wondering why your error was still occurring. It must have been because the app could not be updated with a different signature which makes sense.

Try uninstalling the app and install a newly signed one again. Hard to tell if that'll fix it for you too but if not it would be nice to have a complete stack trace to trouble shoot.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `API_KEY` in the `String` `API_KEY` in `~/utils/MapUtils.java` (in case you tried the Sample Code from **Huawei Codelabs** (**Github**))

or

Try directly adding your `API_KEY` in `MapsInitializer.setApiKey("Your_API_KEY_Here")` in your entrance class (like  `MyActivity` or `MainActivity`).

If those above doesn't help, check the places where `API_KEY` has to be updated / used. In my case, that caused the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I have already solved my problem with the accepted answer.